# Transparent Activity: Not working

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

In my application header bar, i have an icon.On clicking on it show an activity (transparent).

I tried the following code in my activity.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
        <application 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <activity 
                android:name=".Notifications" 
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
                </activity>
        </application>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    </manifest>
```

Activity layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="325dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/notification_list_border"
        android:layout_height="300dp">
        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

notification_list_border.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
     <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <solid android:color="#CCCCCC" />

                <padding
                    android:bottom="3dp"
                    android:left="3dp"
                    android:right="3dp"
                    android:top="3dp" />

                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

But my activity background is still black. What am i doing wrong here?

Please help,
Thanks.

Comment: is below solution work for you??

Comment: @Erma : I think it is not working because of notification_list_border background which has color #CCCCCC. and also try to comment listview because it will make width full screen and don't give width 325dp to parent view instead keep other view inside of it and give it some width

Answer (score 2):

just add style in `Style.xml`

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
```

and this line manifest in activity tag

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
add the following to your activity in manifest.

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />`

and set your actvity some tranparent image to your activity layout.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working:

I changed AndroidManifest.xml as follows,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
        <application 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
        </application>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    </manifest>
```

Reason is that, Application theme was overriding the activity theme

Answer (score -1):

try this style

```
<style name="Invisible" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

and in menifest use this property for activity

```
android:theme="@style/Invisible"
```

Comment: Does anyone have any explaination for -1

Comment: @Erma :
I think it is not working because of notification_list_border background which has color #CCCCCC.
and also try to comment listview because it will make width full screen and don't give width 325dp to parent view instead keep other view inside of it and give it some width

Comment: Thank you for ur reply.I didn't downvote. I will try like you said.